# Rounding Issue with my code. Need it for homework assignment. My code is working correctly. I am using Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is a homework question that has been asked a lot, but I am having trouble with the final formatting of the output. This is the question:
Population
Write a program  that will predict the size of a population of organisms. The program  should ask the user for the starting number of organisms, their average daily population increase  (as a percentage, expressed as a fraction in decimal form: for example 0.052 would mean a 5.2% increase  each day), and the number of days they will multiply. A loop should display the size of the population for each day.

Prompts, Output  Labels and Messages .The three input data should be prompted for with the following prompts: "Enter the starting number organisms: ", "Enter the daily increase : ", and "Enter the number of days the organisms will multiply: " respectively. After the input has been read in successfully, a table is produced, for example:

```
  Day            Organisms 
  ----------------------------- 
  1            200.0 
  2            300.0 
  3            450.0 
  4            675.0
```

Under the heading is a line of 29 dashes followed by one line for each day, showing the day number and the population at the beginning of that day.

Input Validation.Do not accept a number less than  2 for the starting size of the population. If the user fails to satisfy this print a line with this message  "Invalid. Must be at least 2. Re-enter: " and try to read the value . Similarly, do not accept a negative number for average daily population increase , using the message  "Invalid. Enter a non-negative number: " and retrying. Finally, do not accept a number less than  1 for the number of days they will multiply and use the message  "Invalid. Enter 1 or more: ".

That is my code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Population
{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   double organism;
   int days;
   double increase;
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the starting number organisms: ");
   organism =  input.nextDouble();
   while(organism < 2){
       System.out.print("Invalid. Must be at least 2. Re-enter: ");
        organism =  input.nextDouble();
    }
   System.out.print("Enter the daily increase: ");
   increase = input.nextDouble();
   while(increase < 0){
       System.out.print("Invalid. Enter a non-negative number: ");
        increase = input.nextDouble();
    }
   System.out.print("Enter the number of days the organisms will multiply: ");
   days = input.nextInt();
   while(days < 1){
       System.out.print("Invalid. Enter 1 or more: ");
        days = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Day     Organisms");
           System.out.println("-----------------------------");
           System.out.println("1"+ "        " +organism);
           for( int i = 2; i <= days; i++){
               organism = organism*(increase + 1);
               System.out.print(i+"     "+organism);
               System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

The problem I am having is when I submit it online. The output my code produces after 20 days with 0.4 or 40% rate of increase and initial amount of 20 organisms  is this:

Days          Organisms
20&rarr&rarr11952.607917897816↵

What it wants is this:
20&rarr&rarr11952.607917897836↵

This may be unclear. It is how the errors are being shown using Myprogramminlab(a web application to submit homework).
&rarr means right arrow which is a tab and the number 11952 is the number of organisms, but it is being rounded differently.

Also, at 3 days:

Expected is 39.2              My Ouptut is 39.19999999999996

It is basically a small rounding issue. Please help

Comment: You are aware that this is a very small fraction of an organism? I would round to a full integer for output unless there is a requirement to output the full monty.

Comment: You cannot expect to do better than this with floating-point math.  Your `increase` variable isn't even able to hold the number 0.4.  It will actually hold 0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625.  You'll have to explore a class like `BigDecimal` if you want exact accuracy.  Check out http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/ for more information (although I've been told that it has some bugs that I haven't fixed yet, but it will show you what happens when you try to assign 0.4 to a `double`).

Comment: @Fildor At the moment I am only interested in trying to match the expected value.

Comment: If the requirement urges using double instead of bigdecimal, you vould also try using f (x)=n * (1+rate)^x

Comment: @Fildor Agree, thats actually what I suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really small fraction, and in the cases of populations I think it doesn't really matter. If It was up to me I would accept your solution without hesitation.

You can however reach a little more precision even if you use simple doubles, if you write your code like this:

```
double multiplication = 1;
for( int i = 1; i <= days; i++){
    System.out.print(i+"     "+organism*multiplication);
    multiplication = multiplication * (increase + 1);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Floating point types have the property that they have a bigger precision for number with a smaller absolute value. The value of `multiplication` will be significantly smaller then the value of `organism`, so the aggregated rounding (representation) error will also be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I tried what you suggested and it did make it more precise. However, the assignment was still being marked as incorrect. I tried this instead:

```
System.out.println("1"+ "       " +organism);
for( int i = 2; i <= days; i++){
    organism += organism*increase;
    System.out.println(i+"      "+organism);
```

}

For some reason that was okay. Thanks again though, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Ok, so your task was to make the _same_ rounding error as your teacher did? Very meaningful ...